# Lightning:radioGroup type 'Button' size

Tags: lightning-aura-components, radiogroup

Is there a way to create a `lightning:radioButton` with `type='Button'` with same option size?
e.g.

[image]

i wanna set the size like following:

[image]

and obviously center the label inside.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Unless or until the component provides a width option of some sort, you won't be able to manipulate it. You'll need to build your own custom component if you want to have this sort of functionality.